# My selenium says that Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to click a button on a ui-popup but always failed.
HTML: [image]

The web looks like this :

[image]

And I write:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="focussuccesstipsclose"]').click()
```

But it says that

> 'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'

I have found many similar questions on web but they can't solve my problems. I'm a beginner with selenium and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code in this post, not a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry. First time asking question

Comment: Solved.this elemen is not visible from its father element, so use :                   parentElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="focussuccesstips"]')
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="block";',parentElement)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/button').click()

Comment: If you found an answer that works for you, please post it as an answer and accept it. Please clean up your question also for future readers.

Answer (score -1):

**Use javascript executor**

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='focussuccesstipsclose']"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**If element not visible exception is displayed then use webdriver wait method**

Answer (score -1):

This happen when some other element covers the element on which you are going to perform action.
In your case
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="focussuccesstipsclose"]').click()`

Check whether you are performing any other action before this step, if so, then check whether that action covers your "focussuccesstipsclose" `ID` UI on screen, if so then selenium says "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

To come up with such situation, try to click somewhere else on page, which will remove the cover on your `ID`.

I had faced this issue when a Calendar was covering my element.

Comment: Can you do some checks, like - 
The page have single ID having name "focussuccesstipsclose".
You are waiting for sufficient time for the element to get loaded.